# How do i make the time stop after all cards are found

Tags: javascript

I'm making a memory game for a school project, and I have a small issue.
I don't exactly know how I can make the time stop after all cards are found. After a the same card is found it creates the class "checked". So i'm guessing you have to do something with the checked cards.

I made a stopTime function, but i don't know how i can execute it after everything is found.

The time starts, so the only problem is stopping it.
this is the code

```
  
let time = 0;
let TimeStarter = 0;
let seconds = 0;

function startTime () {
  time = setInterval ( function (){
    seconds++;
    Timer.innerHTML = seconds + ' s';                
  }, 1000); 
  startTime = function() {};                  
}

function stopTime ()    {
  clearInterval (time);                 
}


cards.forEach((card) => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
      card.classList.add("clicked");                                 
        if (counter === 0) {
          firstSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
          counter++;
          TimeStarter = 1;                                                  
          if (TimeStarter === 1) {
            startTime();
          }
          
        } else {
          secondSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
          counter = 0;


          if (firstSelection === secondSelection) {
            const correctCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card[meme='" + firstSelection + "']");
             if (Player == "player1") {
               score1.innerHTML = parseInt(score1.innerHTML) + 1
                if (score1.innerHTML >= 8)
                  score1.innerHTML = 8;
             } else {
               score2.innerHTML = parseInt(score2.innerHTML) + 1
                if (score2.innerHTML >= 8)
                  score2.innerHTML = 8;
             }                            
            
            correctCards[0].classList.add("checked");
            correctCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
            correctCards[1].classList.add("checked");                        
            correctCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");

            
          } else {
              const incorrectCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.clicked");
      
              incorrectCards[0].classList.add("red");
              incorrectCards[1].classList.add("red");           
        
              setTimeout(() => {
                incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("red");         
                incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
                incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("red");
                incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
              }, 600);
          }  if (Player == "player1") {
               Player = "player2";
                console.log("i am now player 2");
          }  else {
               Player = "player1"
                console.log("i am now player 1");
          }  
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Create a variable like `correctCardCounter = 0`, increment it each time a correct card is picked. then have something lilke `if(correctCardCounter / 2 === cards.length) stopTimer()`

Comment: Sometimes the solution is very simple... and i love programming but sometimes i hate it too lol